# Overloaded operators not working in debugger, but docs say they should

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I have a trivial test project that defines a class with an operator overload.

```
struct v2
{
    float x;
    float y;

    v2 operator+ (const v2& rhs) const
    {
        return { x + rhs.x, y + rhs.y };
    }
};

int main()
{
    v2 a = { 0, 1 };
    v2 b = { 2, 3 };
    v2 c = a + b;
    return 0;
}
```

If I place a breakpoint on the return statement and enter `a + b` in the Watch window I get the following error: `no operator "+" matches these operands` But `a.operator+(b)` will work so clearly the debugger is *capable* of evaluating the function.

However, when I search through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/expressions-in-the-debugger?view=vs-2017) for Visual Studio I can't find anything saying this isn't supported. In fact, I can find [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/0888kc6a%28v%3dvs.100%29#operator-functions) that *explicitly* say operator overloads are supported by the expression evaluator for native C++ as far back as VS 2010.

I've run this in VS 2015 and VS 2017 and both fail to evaluate it. I've tried implementing the operator as both a member function and a top level function and again no joy.

Does anyone have have or source or understand why using overloaded operators in the Watch window doesn't work? Should it work? Is there some subtle setting that needs to be changed?

Comment: A little further up the page of your "docs" link, it says, "A debugger expression cannot call an intrinsic or inlined function unless the function appears at least once as a normal function."  Try making your `operator+` a non-inline function.

Comment: I don't know what it means to 'appear as a normal function', but that sentence is why I have `v2 c = a + b` in the source shown in the question. And as I said it doesn't work as a top level function either (I didn't add inline to it). And just to be sure I added `__declspec(noinline)` to the member variant and it still doesn't work.